# Return path and selected file xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm having trouble returning the name and path of my file on android, how can I do this? My command below already the option to select the file I need only return the name of the selected file and the path that it enters, can anyone tell me how can I do?

```
  private void PicSelected()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetType("file/*");
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Selecione o arquivo"), 0);
        //this.StartActivityForResult(intent, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `OnActivityResult`. In its arguments you will get an `Intent` containing the data you requested with `StartActivityForResult`.

The `Intent` you get back you will be able to get the `Uri`, by just getting the `Data` property, for the file you have picked. From there you will be able to get whatever you need.

Comment: Do you have an example in xamarin